# Using the global Toolkit.addAWTEventListener() method on a specific swing component

Tags: java, swing, events, awt, listener

So I have been trying to figure this out all day and I just cannot find a way to do it. I am working on an assignment that entails the following:

Using the global Toolkit.addAWTEventListener() method, create a general profiling package for profiling the end-users' operation of Swing/AWT GUI components.

Your design should incorporate the following capabilities:

1. attach original listeners using a generalized listener interface.
2. multiple listeners active at the same time.
3. listen to specific components.
4. listen to components of specified types.
5. listen to all components within a specific SWING/AWT container.
6. listen for specific types of AWT events.
7. 1-6 used in combination.

Now I am certainly not looking for someone to just do this whole thing for me, I feel like once I get past this one major obstacle I'll be able to figure a lot of this out. What I have been stuck on is getting the global listener to only listen to a specific component. Here is what I have so far:

A listener interface that extends AWTEventListener:

```
    import java.awt.event.AWTEventListener;

    public interface MyListener extends AWTEventListener{
        public void addGlobalListener();
    }
```

A JComponent Decorator that implements the previous interface. This will allow the addition of these listeners that I will be creating to any JComponent

```
    import java.awt.AWTEvent;
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.Component;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.LayoutManager;
    import java.awt.Toolkit;
    import java.awt.event.AWTEventListener;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.EventObject;
    import javax.swing.JComponent;


public class MyJComponentDecorator extends JComponent implements MyListener {
    protected JComponent child;

public MyJComponentDecorator(JComponent c) {
    child = c;
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.add(child);
}

@Override
public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent e) {
    System.out.println(e);      
}

@Override
public void addGlobalListener() {
    final MyJComponentDecorator component = new MyJComponentDecorator(child);
     Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(component, AWTEvent.MOUSE_MOTION_EVENT_MASK
        | AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK
        | AWTEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK);
     this.add(component);
}

}
```

And my main class for testing:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        MyJComponentDecorator button = new MyJComponentDecorator(new JButton("A Button"));
        button.addGlobalListener();
        frame.getContentPane().add(button, null);

        frame.setVisible(true);

    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

This is currently everything that I have and it compiles and runs just fine, but the global listener is still listening to the entire frame and not just the button as intended. I realize that what I am trying to do sounds counter intuitive trying to get a global listener to not listen globally, but from what the assignment details say it seems like that is what my professor wants so I am really confused. Sorry if this is drawn out I just did not want to leave anything out, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `AWTEventListener` will notify you of ALL the events passing through the `EventQueue`.  You can check the `AWTEvent.getSource` value to see what generated the event.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That managed to solve that problem, I'm sure I'll run into more though.. Much Thanks!